# Best Way To Copy All Projects EXE And DLL Files In A Solution To One Common Folder?

Tags: visual-studio, copy, project, post-build-event, projects-and-solutions

I have a C# Visual Studio solution with about 15 projects. When I build the solution I want all DLL and EXE files for each project to go to a common folder (called Deploy).

The way I was thinking about doing it was, for each project's *Post-build Event Command Line* section put the following commands:

```
IF NOT EXIST $(SolutionDir)Deploy (
    'If directory does not exist, create it
    MKDIR $(SolutionDir)Deploy
) ELSE (
    'Delete directory to make sure it's "clean"
    RMDIR /F /S /Q $(SolutionDir)Deploy
    MKDIR $(SolutionDir)Deploy
)
'Copy executable and required DLLs to Deploy directory
COPY /Y $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)Deploy
COPY /Y $(TargetDir)*.dll $(SolutionDir)Deploy
```

The problem with doing it this way, however, is I have 15 projects and would have put this in each individual project's post build event section and also, every time I add a new project, I would have to remember to do the same for it.

I checked the solution file properties and did not see a way to set a solution-wide post build event to copy all the files so I did a few Google searches.

One page said to use a C++ *Makefile* project. I added this type of project to my solution and clicked on the project properties page and found that there is a section under *Configuration Properties->NMake* with the following:

- Build Command Line
- Rebuild All Command Line
- Clean Command Line

Using the *Makefile* project's Command Line option poses a similar problem to above. Many different commands to copy each of my 15 project's output files such as:

```
COPY /Y $(SolutionDir)Project1\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.exe $(SolutionDir)Deploy
COPY /Y $(SolutionDir)Project2\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.exe $(SolutionDir)Deploy
...
COPY /Y $(SolutionDir)Project15\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.exe $(SolutionDir)Deploy
```

There is another apparent problem with doing it this way. As you can see I took advantage of the $(SolutionDir) and $(ConfigurationName) macros but I had to hard-code each project name.
I didn't see any macros like $(AllProjects), $(AllProjectDirs), etc.

Also, it appears that command line commands for *Makefile* projects are for building, not post-build events, so I gave up on this idea altogether.

I then tried using a *Visual Studio Installer* project. After adding the project to my solution I right-clicked the project and saw that there was an *Add->Project Output...* option. This brought up a dialog allowing me to add one of my other project's *Primary Output*. I repeated this for each of my other projects and rebuilt.

What resulted was an .MSI file in the output folder. I then opened installer project properties and changed the *Package files* option to *As loose uncompressed files* and rebuilt. The output folder now contained all my project's EXE and DLL files!

Most people would be satisfied at this point and move on but I am the kind of person who likes to find the best way to do things.

There was one thing I didn't like about using the installer project option, the fact that, besides copying the files from all my projects, it also created an MSI file (which I don't need) and I didn't see any option tell it not to create one.

Can anyone recommend a another/better way to accomplish my goal of copying all project output files to a single folder?

Thank you.

P.S. I was thinking I could just make a batch file to search and copy all the EXE and DLL files to the Deploy folder but I would have to run the batch file outside of the Visual Studio IDE and also hard-code the configuration folder (Debug or Deploy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just change the Output Directory of the C++ projects? See [How to: Change the Build Output Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410.aspx).

- On the menu bar, choose Project, Properties.
- Expand the Configuration Properties node, and choose General.
- Change the Output Directory value to the new output directory.

If you want both options, you can also create multiple configurations for your VS projects and solutions, similar to the standard "Debug" and "Release" ones. Create a new configuration from one of the existing ones, then change the output directory and save. Now you can just switch the configuration at the solution level to build into another directory. See this link for detailed steps:

[How to: Create and Edit Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I briefly thought about that but I also like the idea of having each project's build go to their own independent output folder. I will research the link you suggest and read more. There might be an option to have each project's build go to more than one folder (the default and a common folder).

Comment: Thank you again for the reply! Your solution works, however it has a similar issue to using custom post build steps for each project. It requires that I configure each individual project. I realize this would be something that I would have to only do one time but as I stated in my original post I would like to find the "best" or "easiest" way to do this and having to change the settings of only one project rather than all of them seems more appealing to me.

Comment: I think I am going to just keep things the way I currently have them. An installer project that copies the files and just ignore the MSI file that gets generated. Thank you. :)